# Eliminar luis de mi consulta en prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Estoy generando el siguiente codigo en prolog.

```
%Base de echos
%

progenitor(jose,luis).
progenitor(jose,carlos).
progenitor(jose,cristina).

progenitor(maria,luis).
progenitor(maria,carlos).
progenitor(maria,cristina).

varon(jose).
mujer(maria).

%REGLAS
%

padre(X,Y):- progenitor(X,Y),varon(X).
madre(X,Y):- progenitor(X,Y),mujer(X).
hermanos(X,X):-padre(Z,X),padre(Z,Y);madre(Z,X),madre(Z,Y).
```

Pero al consultar el prolog, hermanos(X,luis). me devuelve X=luis,X=carlos,X=cristina, cuando deberia devolver solo carlos y cristina, sin luis ¿Dónde esta mi error?

Answer (score 0):

Veo varios errores, por un lado el cabezal nombra dos veces a X, y por otro parece que ya consideras hermanos aunque sean medio hermanos (eso depende de como lo quieras).

Para el caso en que consideras hermanos únicamente cuando comparten padre y madre podrías escribir esto:

```
hermanos(X,Y):-
  padre(Z,X),
  padre(Z,Y), % X e Y tienen el mismo padre Z
  X \= Y,     % X no es Y
  madre(W,X), % X e Y tienen la misma madre W
  madre(W,Y).
```